# How to fetch and display data from Django Model without invoking the URL

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a Class-Based ListView as shown below:

```
class JobByStateView(ListView):
    model               = State
    template_name       = 'jobs/jobs_by_state.html'
    context_object_name = 'state_list'
    ordering            = ['name']
    paginate_by         = 15
```

I have added the path to urls.py file as shown below:

```
path('jobs/', JobByStateView.as_view(), name='job-by-state'),
```

And this how my template looks:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
          {% for state in state_list %}
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"5" == False %}
            <li>
              <a href="#">{{state.name}}</a>
            </li>
            {% else %}
            <li>
              <a href="#">{{state.name}}</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I try to access this templates via the url (http://localhost:8000/jobs) it works as expected and displays the data on the screen. But when I try embed this template within another template as shown below, nothing gets displayed on the web page.

```
{% include 'jobs/jobs_by_state.html' %}
```

I would like to display this template as a widget within another template.

Really appreciate, if anyone could please help me in fixing this issue.

Thank you so much in advance for your time and help!

=========================================================================

The other page template is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_content %}

{% include 'carousel.html' %}

{% for job in job_list %}
<div class="listing-wrapper">
    <div class="listing-container border-top border-bottom">
        <a href="{{ job.get_absolute_url }}">
        <h2 class="heading mt-3 mb-1 mx-2 d-inline-block">{{ job.title}}</h2>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}


{% if is_paginated %}
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center my-4">
  {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link bg-dark text-white" href="?page{{page_obj.previous_page_number}}">&larr; Previous Page</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link bg-dark text-white" href="?page{{page_obj.next_page_number}}">Next Page &rarr;</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

{% include 'jobs/jobs_by_state.html' with state_list=state_list %}

{% endblock page_content %}

{% block page_sidebar %}

{% include 'simple_search_widget.html' %}

<!-- Social Sharing Buttons -->
<div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons mt-4"></div>

<!-- Newsletter Widget -->
{% include 'newsletter_widget.html' %}

{% endblock page_sidebar %}
```

The view for the parent template is as shown below:

```
class JobList(ListView):
    model               = Job
    template_name       = "jobs/job_listings.html"
    context_object_name = "job_list"
    ordering            = ['-published_date']
    paginate_by         = 10
```

Comment: And what if you try this `{% include 'jobs/jobs_by_state.html' with state_list=state_list %}`, where right part of `state_list=state_list` should be your actuall variable name you passed in context to parent template.

Comment: @Charnel I did try that, but nothing got changed.

Comment: Please include the template and view of the other page.

Comment: @schillingt I have added the parent template and views for your kind reference.

Comment: Is there an item in the template context for `JobList` called `state_list`?

Comment: @ChidG No I don't have any context named state_list within JobList

Comment: @Shahzan, ok, well you are referring to that variable in your template like this: `{% include 'jobs/jobs_by_state.html' with state_list=state_list %}`. So if the variable isn't in the context, it can't be passed to the included template, and so the included template won't display anything.

Comment: @ChidG thanks for your help, indeed your solution fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution from @Charnel and @ChidG worked.

@Shahzan, ok, well you are referring to that variable in your template like this: {% include 'jobs/jobs_by_state.html' with state_list=state_list %}. So if the variable isn't in the context, it can't be passed to the included template, and so the included template won't display anything.